# Jquery replace text every 2 seconds with words from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to replace a text in a span with the id "words" with words from an array every 2 seconds

```
$('#words').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    $(this).delay(3000).text('word2').fadeIn(1000);
$(this).delay(5000).text('word3').fadeIn(1000);
$(this).delay(7000).text('word4').fadeIn(1000);
```

This is what I've got but obviously it stops working after 7 seconds.. how can I repeat this? Or even use an array to hold the words.. Thank you!

Comment: setInterval() method is pretty good for that. Here's some minor doc: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp Hit me if you have problems with closure afterward!

Comment: Hum wait. You want to replace EVERY WORDS but not at the same time is that it? I'll post an answer for that

Comment: Yes right the words should change every few seconds.. so every 2 seconds a different word

Comment: To make the example more clear, could you post it as a working snippet or fiddle?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()` to do this:

```js
$(function () {
  count = 0;
  wordsArray = ["Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Alpha"];
  setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $("#word").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="word">Alpha</div>
```

Comment: Well, I was about to finish my answers, but yours' already complete. I'll stick to this one

Comment: @PraveenKumar maybe you know if it is possible to change `setInterval` time depending on word?

Comment: @o.O Everything is possible, but just tough.

Comment: @PraveenKumar actually not with `setInterval` only with `setTimeout`

Comment: @o.O That's what I believe I said in an another question.

Answer (score 3):

This is easily achievable using just Vanilla JS (normal JS without jQuery) as shown below.

Create a `setInterval()` loop to run every 2 seconds and randomize each time to get a different array element.

```js
var names = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'];

setInterval(function() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = names[rand];
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="name">test</div>
```

If you want to have a fading effect (as mentioned in a comment) your best option will be to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code to swap between two sentences on a website FR -> EN -> FR -> ...

**js** based on @praveen-kumar-purushothaman solution :

```
count = 0;
wordsArray = [
    'Texte en français incluant des <strong>balises html</strong>.',
    'Text in french including <strong>html tags</strong>.'
];
setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $("#mytext").fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).html(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(500);
    });
}, 5000);
```

**html** with first text displayed in french :

```
<h1 id="mytext">
    Texte en français incluant des <strong>balises html</strong>.
</h1>
```

Hope it helps some.